# Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller::show does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-7

I just have upgraded one of my project from `laravel` version `5.2 to 7.1` But now I have started getting following error

```
Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller::show does not exist.
```

I know there is not a function named show in my controller class. But if there is any way to trigger custom named method instead of `show()` while declaring resource attribute in `web.php` file.
Here is my resource declaration in `web.php`

```
Route::resources([
      'first', 'FirstController',
      'second','SecondController'
]);
```

Can I make some customization to tackle this situation.

Comment: Why not rename your custom named method to show()? Or add a `show()` method in your controller that triggers/runs your custom named method?

Comment: actually I don't wanna use show() method.as there are too many other methods which I have in my controller classes.

Comment: Then maybe use different controllers, one "resource" controller (with `index()`, `create()`, `edit()` etc) and another for all your other methods